# How do I change the BackColor and Font color of a textbox using buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntunq.jpg

This is my Form, I have to change the BackColor or the Font color of the textbox depending on which one the user wants to change *Look at bottom right buttons*.

I don`t know how to be able to change the BackColor while being able to change the font color.

Comment: Click event => textBox1.BackColor = the color you want.  You really need to show us your code if you can't get that going.

Comment: I didn't really add anything in my code yet. I probobly didn't explain myself correctly. I need to be able to press one of the buttons at the bottom right (Either the back color or the font color) then click one of the color and change the color of my textbox to the color that I clicked. Exemple:  If(backColorButton = clicked)&&(redButton = clicked) then textbox.BackColor = Color."Red". That's kinda what I'm trying to do but  that code won't work.

Comment: You could use a checkbox to switch between setting for- and backcolor and then code a common click event for the colorpanels using `sender as Panel` (or whatever they are) and its backcolor. Note that 'equals' is writtten `==` nor `=`, which is an assignment! Or you could use left and right buttons. Make sure the user knows how it works..!

Comment: I have to use a button that's the problem, It would be a lot easier with a check box.

Comment: Create some variables where store the values of font and background colors. Then, on button click, use these variables to update the textbox values.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (in the button's on click function):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        textBox1.BackColor = Color.Black;
        textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

Instead of adding logic to see what button was pushed, just use that particular button's on click event function to set the colors as you want them to be. Or as suggested, use checkboxes to choose the backgroundr and the font colors and then add the color changing logic to the button...